# MySQL SELECT using column name given by PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of users where there are five columns dedicated to a short message for each day of the week: 'mon_subject', 'tue_subject' etc., which I'm using to make five < select > boxes for each day of the week. The list of users will be the same for each day, but the subject associated with them will vary per dropdown. I'm trying to make my database searching algorithm more efficient, so instead of doing a database query five times, I've tried this:

```
echo "<select>";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY lastname ASC";
$usersResult = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
function genScheduleEditor($date) {
    include("mysqli_config.php");
    global $usersResult;
    //loop does this #of users times:
        $dayD = date("D", $date);
        $subjectDay = $dayD . "_subject"; //'Mon_subject' etc.
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($usersResult,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $name = $row['username'];       
        $subject = $row['$subjectDay'];
        echo "<option>$subject etc.</option>;
}
echo "</select>";
```

That's the gist of the program. Then the genScheduleEditor() will cycle through five dates to produce five < select > boxes. The problem is that putting a variable into

```
$row['$someColumnName']
```

doesn't seem to work. How can I get around this, where I don't have to do five database queries with different column names?

Comment: `$row[$subjectDay]` - no `'` around the varname

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code:

```
$subject = $row['$subjectDay'];
```

Means the entry in the `$row` array with a key that is literally *dollar-sign* "subjectDay". What you want is that variable:

```
$subject = $row[$subjectDay];
```

Don't do things like `'$x'` or `"$x"` to avoid problems like this. It's pointless and possibly harmful.

Comment: This is good advice but can you give me a specific example of what you mean?

Comment: In shell scripting you sometimes have to do `"$x"` with the surrounding quotes due to interpolation issues. If you do this in PHP it will work in a similar fashion, but it's also pointless and wasteful, plus using single quotes negates the interpolation. This is how [PHP string interpolation works](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), it's selective based on the type of quotes used.